ERROR: (gcloud.access-context-manager.perimeters.update) Error parsing [perimeter]. The [perimeter] resource is not properly specified
I am trying to set up Products for an Apigee on Google Cloud and get the error Products were not loaded successfully. Error: no connections available from the Apigee connect agent(s): refer documentation to triage further., which is a known issue. So as suggested by https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/release/known-issues, issue id 242213234 I follow the Workaround: "Manually create an egress rule, such as the following:"
- egressTo:
    operations:
    - serviceName: "iamcredentials.googleapis.com"
      methodSelectors:
      - method:
    resources:
    - projects/$MY_PROJECT_NUMBER
  egressFrom:
    identityType: ANY_IDENTITY


*NOTE: Originally there was an indentation issue when I copied the yaml from the page which I believe I have fixed.
*
So, after fixing indentation errors, I run the following...

gcloud access-context-manager perimeters update iamcredentials.googleapis.com --set-egress-policies=load-apigee-product-egress-rule.yaml

... and get the following...
ERROR: (gcloud.access-context-manager.perimeters.update) Error parsing [perimeter].
The [perimeter] resource is not properly specified.
Failed to find attribute [policy]. The attribute can be set in the following ways: 
- provide the argument `perimeter` on the command line with a fully specified name
- provide the argument `--policy` on the command line
- set the property `access_context_manager/policy`

I had no rules, so I have created a policy to be associated with VPC Networks, but I don't know how to identify the id, which I assume I apply as follows.

gcloud access-context-manager perimeters update iamcredentials.googleapis.com --set-egress-policies=load-apigee-product-egress-rule.yaml  --policy=??????

